# Bosch battery not charging

Tags: battery

Bosch 400 battery pack, that I have not used for a long time. The lights are not lighting, tried to reset and got nothing.

Comment: It may be dead.  Or maybe you're just not making good contact with the charger.

Comment: Batteries are like muscles - if they don't get used, they wither away.   How long has it been since you last charged this battery?  Try and think back.

Comment: Lithium batteries die when stored in an uncharged state. They should be stored 80% charged. Applies to camera, phone, GPS and e-bike batteries similarly.

Comment: charger seems to be making good contact and is putting out voltage ( i am an electrician by trade). Battery probably wasn't used for about a year or two. I would recharge the battery every now and then, but this was clearly my fault as I work too much and never seem to take the time to ride my bike! Just trying to figure out if there is anything I can do before I try buying a new battery.

Comment: Don't blame you for trying, since those batteries cost a bundle.  You might see if there is a shop such as "Batteries Plus" in your area that has sophisticated test tools and sometimes the capability to replace cells in a battery.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Daniel.